# mod_rewrite request to pretty url

Tags: mod-rewrite

let's say i have a url of the form: *myurl.com/index.php?m=1* and i want to map it to *myurl.com/aboutus*, that means, i want the browser to show the latter url in the bar above.
so what i do first is to catch *aboutus* and map it to *index.php?m=1*.

```
RewriteRule ^aboutus$ /index.php?m=1
```

now if i type myurl.com/aboutus, the proper page is shown, BUT i wanna have it the opposite way as well, so even when i type /index.php?m=1, i want the browser to show /aboutus.

how can i achieve that with mod_rewrite?

any help is appreciated!

cheers,
b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =m=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/index.php
RewriteRule ^.* /aboutus? [R=301]


RewriteRule ^aboutus /index.php?m=1 [QSA]
```

**Update #1**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =m=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/index.php
RewriteRule ^.* /kepek? [R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =m=2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/index.php
RewriteRule ^.* /paroknak? [R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =m=3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/index.php
RewriteRule ^.* /magam? [R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =m=4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/index.php
RewriteRule ^.* /kapcsolat? [R=301]


RewriteRule ^kepek /index.php?m=1&redirected=1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^paroknak /index.php?m=2&redirected=1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^magam /index.php?m=3&redirected=1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^kapcsolat /index.php?m=4&redirected=1 [QSA]
```

Comment: that works, but how can i do it for the other numbers as well? sorry, my question was not generalised at all :(

Comment: If there are a lot of those numbers I would suggest to make redirects from /index.php?m=... request to a proper named pages in index.php itself. Just check the QUERY_STRING.

Comment: there are only 4, and i cannot modify index.php :-/

Comment: Only 4? Then just create similar sections as shown above for every number you have.

Comment: if i just simply copy the lines above (except the 1 line) and change m=1 to {2,3,4} and aboutus to other strings, i get 310: too many redirects.

Comment: You are certainly doing something wrond.

Comment: @Balázs Mária Németh, you will need to add the `&redirected=1` to your RewriteRules, as indicated in the updated answer by @akond.  Otherwise, you will continue to get the endless loop of redirects.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works :) now it's time for me to get the API and understand this, but you put me on the right way i guess!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to map numbers to pages like 1->about, 2->news...?

Also, your desired behavior sounds like an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i want. and for me it looks also like an infinite loop, but i don't want any parameters shown in the url, but i already have the page and in the html the links are coded with params, like regular get urls, so i cannot modify them to be pretty :(

Answer (score -2):

```
RewriteRule ^aboutus$ /index.php?m=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php\?m=1$ /aboutus [301,L]
```

Comment: This rule is actually backwards. The reason it gives you a 500 error is that the file 'aboutus' does not exist.

Comment: This is wrong for a few reasons.  The 500 error is actually because the flag on the 2nd rule is incorrect, it should be `[R=301,L]`.  Also, since the user indicated that the rules are in a `.htaccess` file, the RewriteRules will not match with a leading `/`.  Also, the first group of a `RewriteRule` cannot match against a querystring, therefore needing a `RewriteCond` using the `%{QUERY_STRING}`